# * regex in terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04, wildcards

On Ubuntu 20.04, the terminal doesn't seem to recognize the *regex.

Example, on 18.04 and other prior releases I could just typed and entered

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted*
```

and it would automatically pick both **ubuntu-restricted-extras** and **ubuntu-restricted-addons** package.

But, on 20.04 it seems to throw an error saying

> can't find package ubuntu-restricted*

Is there anyway to get the previous behavior on terminal back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use globs was apparently removed, re-added, and the fix queued up for release (see [relevant bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1872200)).  In the meantime, you can instead use regex patterns but they need to be positively identified as regex.  For instance, you can do `apt install '^ubuntu-restricted'` which I think should be the equivalent to what you want.